# All possible multi sets out of a 3 element set

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We want to know how many possible multi sets can be formed from a set that has only $3$ elements.

My try:

If we look at the multiplicities we get:

$\mu(a_1) = 4 \implies \mu(a_2) = 0 \implies \mu(a_3) = 0$ , we can do this 3 times.
$\mu(a_1) = 3 \implies \mu(a_2) = 1 \implies \mu(a_3) = 0$ we can do this $2 \cdot 3$ times

$\vdots$

However I know there is a faster way. So if we distinguish between the three elements, I guess we can't use $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$, with formula $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$.

Is it correct if I use stirling number here: $S(4,3)$

Comment: @MathLover Yes I think we have to distinguish between them, that's why on the second thought I think that instead of stirling number, we would have to use something else, I thought about partitioning of the natural numbers $V(4,3)$, but I don't know if it is for distinguishing between them.

Comment: Are you choosing a multiset with $4$ elements?

Comment: I think I got your question. I got confused as I saw $4$ but it was not mentioned anywhere that you were looking for multiset with $4$ elements. You can of course apply stars and bars. If there are $n$ elements in set $A$ and you are making a multiset $B$ of $r$ elements choosing elements from set $A$ with repetition, the problem is equivalent to solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + .. + x_n = r$.

Answer (score 1):

The most suitable approach is to use generating functions , because of the fact that the number of elements of the multiset is not stated , i will find it for size of $n$.

Then ,write the generating function of each element such that

- For the first element: $$1+x+x^2+..+x^k+..= \frac{1}{1-x}$$
- For the second element: $$1+x+x^2+..+x^k+..= \frac{1}{1-x}$$
- For the third element: $$1+x+x^2+..+x^k+..= \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Then , find the coefficient of $x^n$ *[in the expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2F%281-x%29%29%5E3)* of $$\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg)^3$$ where $n$ is the size of desired multiset.

Comment: what about if the multi set has  exactly four elements?

Comment: Could I go with the stirling number then ?

Comment: @VLC if the multiset has exactly $4$ element , find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion , it will count such sets : $\{a,a,a,a\},\{a,b,c,c\},.....,\{b,c,b,c\},....$ etc. where $a,b,c$ are the elements of this set

Comment: @VLC Stirling number of second kind is to divide distinct elements into groups , but your problems necessiate repeating elements , so it could not work

Comment: what about partitioning of natural numbers, so in this case, $4$ into partition of $3$ natural numbers. $p_k(n) = p_k(n − k) + p_{k−1}(n − 1)$

Comment: @VLC if we talk about partition of  numbers into groups, then striling numbers can be used , but it is bot related to constructing multisets